# which is the Memory efficient way to pass the string as argument to a function.?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

can any one tell me .Is there any benefit of passing string as  func(string& ) instead of  func( string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing an object by reference means, well, that you're passing the **reference** by value, instead of passing the **object** by value, which means that you have to made a copy at function invocation.

However, passing-by-reference introduces a new set of questions which you must be aware of:

1. does the function modifies or not the passed object? If it does not, you should put in the `const` modifier
2. does the function need to modify the object, but not exposing the modifications outside the function boundaries? In that case what you really want is a copy.
3. does the function stores somewhere/somehow the reference of the passed object? In that case, you have to understand how object ownership is passed and when it's safe to delete it. You may want to use [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) to deal with these issues

The point is: just because passing-by-reference makes function invocation cheaper does not means that you must use it in any case.

Comment: In case 2, I would still put as parameter a `const &` and create a copy inside of the function, especially considering that perhaps the function will fail/return *before* having to do the copy.

Comment: @xanatos yes, it is a possibility, but unless this function is called heavily and the probability of returning before having to do the copy is high, it is simpler to pass the argument by value.

Comment: (and I think that Steve Jessop's argument in the Björn Pollex's answer is a good one in this dispute.)

Answer (score 4):

`func(string &)` passes the string by reference. This means that it will not be copied, and that the function can modify it.

`func(string)`  passes the string by value. This means that a copy will be created, and that the function can only modify it's own local copy of that string.

To pass a string without copying, but prevent it from being modified use `func(const string&)`.

If your function needs to take a copy of the argument anyway, passing by value is preferable.

Comment: Plus you should consider `func(const string&)` for cases when `func` does not need to modify its parameter. And if you even consider having `func(string)` it means you should use `func(const string&)` as your function cannot modify this param anyway...

Comment: "If your function needs to take a copy of the argument anyway, passing by value is preferable." How would that help?

Comment: @Paul: it would make the function slightly easier and less error-prone to write, since it wouldn't need separate variables for the argument and the copy it makes.

Comment: @Paul: it enables some potential optimizations. For example consider `func1(std::string x) { /* use x for something */ }` vs. `func2(const std::string &y) { std::string x(y); /* use x for something */ }`, and assume that both are off in some other TU or dll where they can't be inlined. Then if I call `func2("hi")`, a temporary is created for the parameter, and then copied in the function body. If I call `func1("hi")`, then I'm eligible for copy elision or a C++11 move construction, no need to actually copy a `string` object.

Comment: Or actually, maybe with `func1` the parameter is directly constructed from "hi", and any copy/move is forbidden. I can't remember the semantics of implicit conversions in function arguments, but whichever way the rules are, `func2` can't avoid copying one string to another, because it doesn't know whether its parameter is a reference to a temporary, whereas `func1` either might avoid it or must avoid it, one of the two.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a reference will usually be more efficient for complex types, but it should be a reference to `const` unless you want the function to be able to modify it:

```
void f(string);        // function gets its own copy - copying may be expensive
void f(string&);       // function can modify the caller's string
void f(string const&); // function can read the caller's string, but not modify it
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `func(const string& )` instead of `func(string& )` to make sure that the passed-by-reference parameter does not get altered mistakenly inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass it as `string` the string first gets copied and the copy is sent to the function. The best way to pass expensive objects such as strings, if you don't want the function to modify them, is by `const string&`.

The `const` is important. First of all, it ensures the string won't be modified inside the function. Also, you wouldn't be able to pass a literal to function without using it `func("this is a litearal because it isn't inside a variable")`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference is typically better than passing by value as far as performance is concerned (exclude the built-in data types). So yes `func(string&)` is better than `func(string)`. Provided that the passed `string` can be modified when the function finishes. If you don't intend to change the `string` then use `func(const string&)`.

On the other note, I remember reading somewhere that in STL, the `string`s are optimized. Means if you pass `string` by value, it may not necessarily create a new string on heap. So passing by value may not be that much expensive as you expect. e.g.

```
string s1 = "hello";  // new buffer allocated on heap and copied "hello"
string s2 = s1;  // s2 and s1 both 'may' refer to same heap 
...
s1 += " world"; // s2 continue referring to old heap ...
                // new heap created to accomodate "hello world" referred by s1
```

Comment: To give a little more detail on the `string` optimisation thing: `strings` are [COW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)'d. When you pass a `string` by value, a new `string` is created, but the underlying data (e.g. character array) is shared between the original `string` and the new `string`. Therefore there is some overhead but not much, unless the local copy is modified. **EDIT:** looks like you edited to explain this while I was writing my comment.

Comment: @Mac That is not necessarily true, some implementations do COW, some don't, and I think I read somewhere that some of the changes in C++11 made it impossible to offer a compliant standard library with COW strings, but I am not sure of this last part.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: absolutely right - what I intended to say was `string`s are *typically* COW'd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Passing a reference is always efficient.
A string may be stored by value and the copying may take as long as O(n) (i.e., copying takes time proportional to the length of the string). It will also cause heap memory to be allocated, which is usually far more expensive than the copy.
You may also consider passing by reference-to-const i.e. func(const string &) to avoid any unintenional changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use rvalue reference optimizations by using move semantics.

```
void func(string &&s)
{
    myS = std::move(s);
}
```